# Subquery returns more than 1 row on 2nd insert

Tags: php, html, insert, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables:

tblUser:

```
+------+-----------+
|  id  |   Name    |
+------+-----------+
```

tblItems(this table accepts multiple checkbox value depending on how many user selected):

```
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  id  |  items    |    name_id    |
+------+-----------+---------------+
```

`name_id` will get the value of id in `tblUser`.
I use this code to get the value of id of `tblUser` to `name_id`:

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++){
    $sql2="INSERT INTO tbl_trainings VALUES (NULL, '".$checkbox[$i]."', (SELECT id FROM tbl_info))";
    $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
 }
```

It works fine on the first `INSERT` of data that will look like this in database:

```
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  id  |  items    |    name_id    |
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  1   |  Bucket   |    1          |
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  2   |  Tree     |    1          |  
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  3   |  House    |    1          |
+------+-----------+---------------+
```

But in the next or second `INSERT` of data will be an error. The error is

**Subquery returns more than 1 row** from the `mysql_error();`

By the way, this is the full codes:

```
if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit"){
    $sql1="INSERT INTO tblUser VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lname')";
    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++){
    $sql2="INSERT INTO tblItems VALUES (NULL, '".$checkbox[$i]."', (SELECT id FROM tblUser))";
        $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
    }
}

if($result2 && result1){
    echo"<center>";
    echo"<h1>";
    echo "SUCCESSFUL!";
    echo"</h1>";
    echo"</center>";
}
else {
    echo "ERROR". mysql_error();
}
```

And the desired output in the database would be:

```
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  id  |  items    |    name_id    |
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  1   |  Bucket   |    1          |
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  2   |  Tree     |    1          |  
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  3   |  House    |    1          |
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  4   |  Tree     |    2          |  
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  5   | Air plane |    2          |
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  6   | Bucket    |    3          |
+------+-----------+---------------+
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SELECT id FROM tblUser need a where clause telling wich user you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM tblUser
```

returns all ids from the table.

You need use mysql last_insert_id instead:

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO tblUser VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lname')";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
$user_id = mysql_insert_id();
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++){
    $sql2="INSERT INTO tblItems VALUES (NULL, '".$checkbox[$i]."', $user_id)";
    $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
}
```

Please note that the standard mysql functions are deprecated.

Comment: Sorry, I've modified the post.

Comment: almost there... but what's happening is the name_id is: 1 1 2 3 4 5 and in 2nd insert will be 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 (ordered)

Comment: are you asking about input or output? The first input generates an unique id and it will be the same for all further inserts if sql2

Comment: input. the info_id must be 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3. if 2 checkbox were selected on first it will be 1 1 on second insert if 3 checkbox it will be 1 1 2 2 2.

Answer (score 0):

cause of securety reasons you should use prepared statements
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php